# Tensorflow DynamicRnnEstimator AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'key'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am trying to use DynamicRnnEstimator but I am getting a "'list' object has no attribute 'key'" Error.

Code:

```
    feature_names = [
    'FeatureA',
    'FeatureB',
    'FeatureC',
    'FeatureD',
    'FeatureE',
    'FeatureF']
    ...
    feature_columns = [tf.feature_column.numeric_column(k) for k in feature_names]
    print (feature_columns)

    estimator = tf.contrib.learn.DynamicRnnEstimator(problem_type = constants.ProblemType.CLASSIFICATION,
                                                  prediction_type = rnn_common.PredictionType.SINGLE_VALUE,
                                                  sequence_feature_columns = [feature_columns],
                                                  context_feature_columns = None,
                                                  num_units = 5,
                                                  num_classes = 11,
                                                  cell_type = 'lstm', 
                                                  optimizer = 'SGD',
                                                  model_dir = "model",
                                                  learning_rate = 0.1)
    estimator.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn("train.csv"), steps=STEPS)
```

Here's the output:

```
[_NumericColumn(key='FeatureA', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None), _NumericColumn(key='FeatureB', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None), _NumericColumn(key='FeatureC', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None), _NumericColumn(key='FeatureD', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None), _NumericColumn(key='FeatureE', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None), _NumericColumn(key='FeatureF', shape=(1,), default_value=None, dtype=tf.float32, normalizer_fn=None)]

...

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-83-bea117372333> in <module>()
     26                                                   learning_rate = 0.1)
     27 
---> 28 estimator.fit(input_fn=lambda: input_fn("train.csv"), steps=STEPS)

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/deprecation.pyc in new_func(*args, **kwargs)
    314                 'in a future version' if date is None else ('after %s' % date),
    315                 instructions)
--> 316       return func(*args, **kwargs)
    317     return tf_decorator.make_decorator(func, new_func, 'deprecated',
    318                                        _add_deprecated_arg_notice_to_docstring(

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in fit(self, x, y, input_fn, steps, batch_size, monitors, max_steps)
    478       hooks.append(basic_session_run_hooks.StopAtStepHook(steps, max_steps))
    479 
--> 480     loss = self._train_model(input_fn=input_fn, hooks=hooks)
    481     logging.info('Loss for final step: %s.', loss)
    482     return self

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _train_model(self, input_fn, hooks)
    984       global_step_read_tensor = training_util._get_or_create_global_step_read()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    985       with ops.control_dependencies([global_step_read_tensor]):
--> 986         model_fn_ops = self._get_train_ops(features, labels)
    987       ops.add_to_collection(ops.GraphKeys.LOSSES, model_fn_ops.loss)
    988       all_hooks.extend(hooks)

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _get_train_ops(self, features, labels)
   1200       `ModelFnOps` object.
   1201     """
-> 1202     return self._call_model_fn(features, labels, model_fn_lib.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
   1203 
   1204   def _get_eval_ops(self, features, labels, metrics):

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/estimator.pyc in _call_model_fn(self, features, labels, mode, metrics)
   1164     if 'model_dir' in model_fn_args:
   1165       kwargs['model_dir'] = self.model_dir
-> 1166     model_fn_results = self._model_fn(features, labels, **kwargs)
   1167 
   1168     if isinstance(model_fn_results, model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps):

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dynamic_rnn_estimator.pyc in _dynamic_rnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode)
    478       sequence_input = build_sequence_input(features,
    479                                             sequence_feature_columns,
--> 480                                             context_feature_columns)
    481       dropout = (dropout_keep_probabilities
    482                  if mode == model_fn.ModeKeys.TRAIN

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/estimators/dynamic_rnn_estimator.pyc in build_sequence_input(features, sequence_feature_columns, context_feature_columns, weight_collections, scope)
    190   features.update(layers.transform_features(
    191       features,
--> 192       list(sequence_feature_columns) + list(context_feature_columns or [])))
    193   sequence_input = layers.sequence_input_from_feature_columns(
    194       columns_to_tensors=features,

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.pyc in transform_features(features, feature_columns)
    642   """
    643   columns_to_tensor = features.copy()
--> 644   check_feature_columns(feature_columns)
    645   transformer = _Transformer(columns_to_tensor)
    646   for column in sorted(set(feature_columns), key=lambda x: x.key):

/home/judge/anaconda3/envs/ipykernel_py2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/layers/python/layers/feature_column_ops.pyc in check_feature_columns(feature_columns)
    765   seen_keys = set()
    766   for f in feature_columns:
--> 767     key = f.key
    768     if key in seen_keys:
    769       raise ValueError('Duplicate feature column key found for column: {}. '

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'key'
```

Looking at the trace, it concatenates the sequence_feature_columns and context_feature_columns. It starts looking at the result but doesn't find a key. I have printed out the feature_names and they have keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you've wrapped `feature_columns` in a list a second time (giving `[[...]]` rather than `[...]`):

`sequence_feature_columns = [feature_columns],`

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have now changed the call arg to:
sequence_feature_columns = feature_columns
but get
AttributeError: '_NumericColumn' object has no attribute 'insert_transformed_feature'

Comment: As much as I hate to recommend it, it sounds like `DynamicRnnEstimator` hasn't been updated to use the core `tf.feature_columns` yet. Using `tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column` may work around the issue. If that does fix things, feel free to file a bug/feature request.